# Searching a table of implicit ranges (only the minimum value of each range is specified in the row)

Tags: mysql

I have the following table, `price`:

```
CREATE TABLE `price` (
  `price_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMEMT,
  `effective_date` date NOT NULL,
  `min_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This store only sells one product, a widget, and this table specifies the prices for that product as a function of the quantity being purchased (the more you buy, the cheaper the price). We can assume that all columns are indexed for efficiency. Column `effective_date` specifies the starting date when this price goes in effect; we maintain historical price data as well as prices that will go in effect in the future. We would like to know what the price of a widget when bought in a quantity of 7 will be on 12/24/2018. Here is one solution:

```
SELECT `price` FROM `price`
WHERE `effective_date` <= '2018-12-24' AND `min_quantity` <= 7
ORDER BY `effective_date` desc, `min_quantity` desc
LIMIT 0, 1
```

There is a sorting implied by the above SQL, which might not be inefficient if the table is not particularly large. The only other approach I can think of (and that's why I am asking), is much more complicated. It involves first finding the maximum of the effective dates that does not exceed the date in question and then selecting all those rows that match that maximum effective date. Then from those rows you find the maximum value of the minimum quantity that does not exceed the quantity being purchased and then select the one row that matches that maximum.

But is there a better way that this second method, which does not rely on sorting? Or is the way I coded never going to be too inefficient?

Comment: Indexes are key.

Answer (score 0):

the Indexes can **improve your performance** and can **decrease your performance**. it's depend to how you use it on your table because when you index a column it effect on execution plan that DBMS will create for your query.

> you say: We can assume that all columns are indexed for efficiency.

and `order by` will run after finding result

but i think if you Index both `effective_date` and `min_quantity` column it can help to increase your performance.